# How do I to get JSON response in English only using Google Maps API

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, google-maps

When I am posting my query for getting a location in Google Maps API I am getting the follow response:

`descriptionHtml is 1 つ目の角を左に曲がって、<b>central road</b>に入る<div class="google_note">
<b landmarkid="0x390cfcd4e13e8025:0x46d4d92a3bf0456c" class="dir-landmark">Central Revenue Bldg</b>を通過する<div class="dirseg-sub">（300&nbsp;m 先、左手）</div>`

But I want the whole response in English only

Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

I am using Objective-C for Google Maps Api here

//Update...

I found that I have to change something here:

`locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP"];`

Can anyone tell me what should I do here?

Comment: Why are you using `locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP"];` ?

Comment: @jaliya...because I am told to use google api and use Json data according to that..no choice other than using google api :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

[Coordinate (Lat/Lon) to Address (City,Zip, etc) - ReverseGeoCoordinate](http://xxki.com/tutorial/pukiwiki.php?MacOS/iPhone%20-%20MapKit)

Change the below statement

```
locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP"];
```

to

```
locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

[More](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html)